# Ascensor.js IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, ascensor

I am working on a new site, currently hosted [here](http://anukruti.tauqirpervez.com/ascensor.html#/Home). I am implementing a single page design using the Ascensor plugin, found [here](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/). It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, and IE10 and IE9. However, in IE8, the home page loads and then if I click on any of the navigation icons, the page starts shaking, literally shaking left and right very fast, and the browser crashes after a few seconds. I have used Ascensor in IE8 before, and it had worked. I can't even debug as it just crashes without any warning in IE8. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for the past few hours, with no success.

I checked the behavior in IE8 by:

1. Changing the document mode to IE8 in IE10.
2. Using a Win7-IE8 VM

If it helps, I am also using the following jQuery plugins on the page.

1. [CarouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) and [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) for the gallery.
2. [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Also, I am using jQuery 1.8.3 as Ascensor does not run correctly using later versions.

Someone please point me in the correct direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the scrollbar (not sure why it was occurring though). Using the following CSS on the body fixed the issue.

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```